# DESCARGAR DIRECTAMENTE FPDF

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Lo que busco es que al momento de que se genere mi archivo PDF en ves de mostrarlo en el navegador, se descargue directamente en la computadora, he intentado lo siguiente pero realmente no sé en que estoy fallado `$pdf->Output('hola.pdf');`.

También me gustaría saber si es posible que por ejemplo, yo tengo un formulario HTML donde se ingresan los datos y al dar ENVIAR se genera el PDF, en esa parte que se descargue automáticamente el PDF, pero que ya no pueda regresar a la Pagina HTML del formulario.. Espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: Cuál es el error con `$pdf->Output`

Comment: El método `Output` de FPDF admite tres constantes que son: `I,D,F,S`, si pasas `D` por ejemplo se fuerza una descarga del archivo, o `F` crea un archivo local (quizá haya que incluir una ruta en ese caso). Está explicado en la [documentación](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm). Prueba esto por ejemplo: `$pdf->Output(D,'hola.pdf');`